# Calculate a color threshold from within a contour dynamically

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an input image which consists of 3 colors.These colors are circular in shape and nested.

The image is similar to this : 
https://www.google.ie/search?q=red+yellow+blue+nested+circles&client=ms-unknown&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CbQTsOKsM7yhIkCaDOdJHzqnN2Xk-DhItFHm0Zqt6wMB32Tm1CzyzQ7wrXERbVqngEyMBzO57J8UuHLak9WPqWfjV7kgvdJ47BJlKhIJmgznSR86pzcR8SW2ldYWlqIqEgll5Pg4SLRR5hG-6WlMFrVBvioSCdGaresDAd9kEVFfCyyB-AgqKhIJ5tQs8s0O8K0RT790ELynuK8qEglxEW1ap4BMjBHBPar4Jd2NtioSCQczueyfFLhyEY7iP_13IGcsOKhIJ2pPVj6ln41cRTMOWeqZE5oYqEgm5IL3SeOwSZREray5kAy-dzw%3D%3D&tbo=u&ved=0ahUKEwjWzfSC6IbXAhXFbBoKHW3GBrUQuIIBCCM#imgrc=5tQs8s0O8K32hM:

I will be working with several images like this.The imaage is always of the same thing.however dude to different camera , lighting , even printer differences , the actual color can vary. In that it will always be red yellow green in the order showen. By using HSV and thresholds I can easily determine upper and lower values for each color. However If I change to a different set of images theses values are no longer functional.

My idea to overcome this is to look for contours first in the image.
For each contour I would like to get an upper and lower threshold. Using a combination of canny , gaussian and contours I am able to draw contour around each color from testing this seems general enough for purpose.

Where I'm stuck is getting the threshold value from within the contours. Is this possible? Or is there simpler logic I am over looking to achieve this ?

At present I'm using python , but language is secondary.

Comment: have you tried with HSV colorspace, and to use inRange to threhold using the Hue values?

Comment: Hi yes I have used HSV , The problem is that while usingHSV works for a single image or a few images it's not robust enough to work for all images , which is why I'm trying to get the threshold values for each image from the image. The image is printed on paper so little things like light , how much ink the printer had left can slightly change the effectiveness of the thresholding

Comment: Maybe an example of a real image will help a lot more for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks , I will upload a real pic as you suggested.Do you think what I am trying to achieve is possible ?

Comment: it depends on the image, on the strategy you use, and how much error you can have... but mainly it depends on how much the image changes, if not you can try machine learning

Comment: You can change the color space of the image to appropriate one (HSV, LAB etc) and then plot histogram on its color components, where u get three peaks. A threshold around peaks depending on your acceptable error can do the task. If you need something more better, check out for "selective search" where they join segments of objects based on color( and other) similarities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the contours, they will make things harder than necessary.

A better approach could be by classifying the pixels using k-means. Initialize with at least three clusters, centered around green, yellow, red. Maybe one centered on white, for the background.

After convergence you should have the exact colors, together with segmentation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Standard_algorithm

Comment: Thanks , this approach seems interesting. I will try later and update the post.